# Salesforce Communities - Styling

Tags: community, css

Would anyone be able to advise how I can best override the standard css in communities. I have added custom CSS, although it appears that the standard communities css loads after the custom css making it difficult to override the styling. Ideally I would want my CSS to load after the default CSS.

Not an issue for custom modules, as I can used my unique classes, but its a bit of an issue when trying to restyle the standard styles.

Comment: What community type are using - VF and tabs or a template?

Comment: It is the Napili Template

Comment: I've got some similar stuff that I need to do in Napili so I'll see if I can find a solution.